# Android:Listview data not changing inside view pager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I want to display data in a 'tabbed list', which is a view pager and listviews inside each page. For that, I am using two adapters, one for view pager and one for listview. The problem in its implementation is that the listview data is not changing when I switch the pages. Below is the code

```
public class ALTabbedListAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;

    protected ArrayList<String> originalTabsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<OEDataRow> filteredDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<OEDataRow> originalDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String group_key;
    private int num_pages;

    public View mView;
    public ListView mListView;
    public  ALListViewAdapter listViewAdapter; // declared as an inner class below.

    public ALTabbedListAdapter(Context context, String type, ArrayList<String> groupkey_rows, ArrayList<OEDataRow> dataRows) {
        mContext = context;
        originalTabsList = groupkey_rows;
        group_key = type;
        originalDataList = dataRows;
        num_pages = groupkey_rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return num_pages;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return originalTabsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        mView = setupListView(position);// This function call sets up the listview and returns the view, defined below.
        container.addView(mView);
        return mView;

    }

    public ArrayList<OEDataRow> getListViewData(/*OEDataRow row*/String row, ArrayList<OEDataRow> originalDataListParam) {
        ArrayList<OEDataRow> dataRowArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OEDataRow dataRow : originalDataListParam) {
            if (Boolean.toString(dataRow.getBoolean(group_key)).equalsIgnoreCase(row)/*row.getString("name")*/) {
                dataRowArrayList.add(dataRow);
            }
        }
        return dataRowArrayList;
    }

    public View setupListView(int position) {
        View view= ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.tablayout_listview_layout, null);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_listview);
        ArrayList<OEDataRow> finallist = getListViewData(originalTabsList.get(position)/*dataRow*/, originalDataList);
        if(listViewAdapter==null) {
            listViewAdapter = new ALListViewAdapter(finallist);
        } else {
            listViewAdapter.changeFilterData(finallist);
        }
        mListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            }
        });
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }


    public class ALListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public View mListItemView;
        public LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ALListViewAdapter(ArrayList<OEDataRow> dataList) {
            changeFilterData(dataList);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return filteredDataList.size();
        }

        public void changeFilterData(ArrayList<OEDataRow> dataList){
            if(filteredDataList != null) {
                filteredDataList.clear();
            }
            filteredDataList=dataList;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return filteredDataList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if(mListItemView == null) {
                mListItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            }
            //TODO How to make it extendable?
            OEDataRow row = filteredDataList.get(i);
            TextView tv_title = (TextView)mListItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_namefield);
            tv_title.setText(row.getString("name"));

            return mListItemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating only one adapter instance for all view pager views which should not, you have to create new List view adapter instance for each view:

```
     public View setupListView(int position) {
        View view= ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.tablayout_listview_layout, null);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_listview);
        ArrayList<OEDataRow> finallist = getListViewData(originalTabsList.get(position)/*dataRow*/, originalDataList);

        final  ALListViewAdapter alListViewAdapter = new ALListViewAdapter(finallist);
        mListView.setAdapter(alListViewAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Do your stuff...


                alListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I created a new `ALListViewAdapter` in the `setupListView` which gets called inside `instantiateItem` of the Pager adapter. Isn't that what you are saying?

Comment: No, instantiateItem is correct one, but your adapter instance will create only one if you have 10 view's  in View pager, which should not, it should be always new for each view. Updated your setupListView  method code, plz check...

Comment: you have to create new Adapter object for each view pager view.

Comment: Do I need to retain those adapter objects ? Its a dynamic list, so say I have 5 Viewpages, so do I need to create 5 different adapters or I can just change the value of a single adapter, just like how you did in your update?

Comment: yes, need to retain the position wise view adapter if you want to update view out side the "setOnItemClickListener".

Comment: I created an arraylist of adapters but it works only if I switch the tabs in order.`listViewAdapterArrayList.add(position, new ALListViewAdapter(finallist));
        mListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapterArrayList.get(position));`

Comment: 'getListViewData' returns a filtered list, which is passed in the 'ALListViewAdapter'. This happens inside 'setUpListView', which is called inside 'instantiateItem'. Now, if I tap on tabs randomly, it displays wrong data. if I do it in order it works.

Comment: The problem is that `instantiateitem` is called for the next item also, so that view is returned instead of the first one.

Comment: yes "instantiateitem" will be get called for every view Item of view pager, add your all source code here, so I can check...

Comment: I already put up all the code, the listview adapter is declared as an inner class

Comment: It works with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`.

Comment: It works now, I had to move the filteredDataList to the listview adapter, which makes it unique for each adapter. Thanks a lot for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. If you want tab based functionality then manage it in ViewPager and in ViewPager make different Fragment of every Screens and then make code in that.

If you are using fragment method then you can use this method to refresh your listview

```
    @Override
        public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
            super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
            if(menuVisible)
                yourListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

This method invokes the call when your fragment comes in visible area.

Comment: I am not using fragments for every page

Comment: Use it. That will be more efficient.